# Picking the start of convergence $c$ for an integral expression of the Dirichlet $\eta$-function. What happens when $c \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, dirichlet-series

Using the following expression for the Dirichlet [$\eta(s)$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function):

$$\normalsize \eta(s,c) = -\frac{1}{\Gamma(s-c)} \int_0^{\infty} x^{s-c-1}\,\text{Li}_c(-\text{e} ^{-x}) \mathop{dx}$$

one could pick the start of its convergence $c$ for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that $\text{Li}$ is the [polylog-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

*Question (maybe trivial):*

What actually happens to the convergence of the function, when $c \in \mathbb{C}$? Will convergence then start at its absolute value?

Comment: For which $s,c$ does the RHS converge, to $\eta(s)$.

Comment: @reuns It should converge for all $\Re(s) > c$ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$. My question is about convergence when $c \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a)

$$f_c(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^{n+1}n^{-c} e^{-nx}$$ is continuous on $x\ge 0$ with $f_c(0)=\eta(c)$.

(b) whence for $\eta(c)\ne 0$, as $f_c(x)$ has exponential decay as $x\to \infty$, $$\int_0^\infty x^{s-c-1} f_c(x)dx$$ converges and is analytic for $\Re(s)>\Re(c)$.

(a) follows from that $(1+e^x)^k f_c(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^{n+1}n^{-c-k} g_{c,k}(1/n)e^{-nx}$ where $g_{c,k}(t)$ is analytic at $0$ by induction on $k$.